# Get a scrollbar's maximum scroll value

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar

I have a ScrollBar with Maximum of 500, so why is it that when the Thumb is at the end, the value is less then Maximum?
Does this have anything to do with the LargeChange / SmallChange properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also the size of the Scrollbar's body to consider.

If you take the value of the Scrollbar when it is at the end, and subtract it from the it's Maximum, you'll get the size of the Scrollbar's body, or as you called it - Thumb (not familiar with that term).

The size of the Scrollbar's body should be `LargeChange - 1`.